# Crear una API Web de búsqueda para mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, api, curl

Hola he desarrollado un página web que contiene un sistema de búsqueda en PHP y funciona correctamente (llamemos a esta página, web1).
Me gustaría saber como puedo yo ahora desarrollar una API que al introducirla en otra página web (web2) recoja el input del usuario, mi algoritmo en PHP busque en mi base de datos y el resultado sea enviado de vuelta a esa web de tercera y muestre los resultados en su página web (web2).

Un ejemplo sería el de Google, Google tiene una API para paginas web de terceros que al introducirla con un script el usuario puede realizar una búsqueda de contenidos mediante el sistema de Google y le aparecen los resultados en su propia página web.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/query-guide?hl=es-419

Estoy muy perdido porqué no acabo de comprender que lenguaje de programación puedo yo utilizar para poder relacionar mi algoritmo de búsqueda (escrito con PHP) con la interacción en otra página web (web2) y luego poder volver a enviar los resultados.

He encontrado que con JavaScript algo se puede hacer, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), pero no se si eso vale para un input el qual tiene que enviar un dato a mi algoritmo de búsqueda PHP.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

hay muchas formas de hacer una API REST, tambien hay muchos frameworks como en [Slim](https://www.weblantropia.com/2016/08/30/restful-api-api-php-mysql/) que te permite crear una REST a partir de un CRUD.

**Advertencia**:
Crear una API REST es un poco delicado por el tema de seguridad y todo lo relacionado con los CORS, te recomiendo trabajarlo en un modo sandbox si es que manejas información delicada, manejar API KEYS o Bareers en cada solicitud, IP_REQUEST de solicitudes, etc.

En mi experiencia trabajando con REST en PHP solamente la utilizo al backend de mi script con el que voy a manipular el input de la información, y para trabajar con el manejo de la información decidí utilizar Node.JS, es demasiado facil, seguro y todo se crea con librerias.

Si tienes mas dudas o necesitas ayudas solo dinos!

Comment: Gracias @Ruben , entonces en mi caso tendría que considerar el valor que introduce el usuario en esa web y enviarlo mediante un POST ( siguiendo el protocolo HTTP) , después con el parámetro limpio pasarlo por mi algoritmo de búsqueda, encontrar los valores en mi base de datos y volver a enviar a la misma página web que ha hecho la búsqueda los valores respectivos (mediante el protocolo HTTP). ¿Usted me recomienda NodeJS para enviar los parámetros de búsqueda entre diferentes webs? ¿Conoce algún sitio web/ canal dónde pueda yo encontrar información al respecto? Muchas gracias Ruben

Comment: @JackMore La API la hice con [Node.JS](https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/), envias las solicitudes mediante PHP con las funciones de [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-init.php), las API keys van por parte de NODEJS y va escondido en tu PHP script. Mira, te dejo el chat que tengo de ayuda para este tipo de cosas. Si gustas entrar por aca podemos tratarlo mejor https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132274/ayuda

Comment: @JackMore Hola, ya te he dejado mensajes en el chat de ayuda!